# Django login by facebook

Tags: python, django, facebook-login

I am beginner to Django.

I am studying about oauth 2.0 for login. I can actually register and login. Now, I need to implement facebook login and I follow this library.

https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

After I import that and run in my local host, I got these error. I don't know which file/code got issue. How shall I do?

```
oauth2_provider.AccessToken.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AccessToken.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AccessToken.user'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AccessToken.user' or 'AccessToken.user'.

oauth2_provider.Grant.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Grant.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Grant.user'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Grant.user' or 'Grant.user'.

oauth2_provider.RefreshToken.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'RefreshToken.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'RefreshToken.user'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'RefreshToken.user' or 'RefreshToken.user'.

provider.AccessToken.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'AccessToken.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'AccessToken.user'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'AccessToken.user' or 'AccessToken.user'.

provider.Grant.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Grant.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Grant.user'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Grant.user' or 'Grant.user'.

provider.RefreshToken.user: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'RefreshToken.user' clashes with reverse accessor for 'RefreshToken.user'.
HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'RefreshToken.user' or 'RefreshToken.user'.
```